# Validating regular expression

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have been working with this problem for some time and was hoping for some guidance. I am prompting the user to enter "course" info (example `AAA.111#2222_aa-1234`)
I then created a validate function and button for the html page to source from the javascript

Within my isValidInfo function, I can get it to work with:

```
var infoRegExp = /^(\D{3}.\d{3}#\d{4}_\D{2}-\d{4})$/g;
```

with the IF statement BUT the else statement does not produce the "Invalid information" message.

Also once I change the code within the function to be case sensitive ie;

```
/^(\D[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z].\d{3}#\d{4}_\D[a-z][a-z]-\d{4})$/i;
```

the validate function/button does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title>Input Course Info</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src = "course.js"></script>
        <button onclick= "validate()">Validate</button>
    </body>

</html>

function isValidInfo(course) {
    var infoRegExp = /^(\D[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z].\d{3}#\d{4}_\D[a-z][a-z]-\d{4})$/i;
    var result = infoRegExp.test(course);
    return result
}
var course = prompt("Enter course information (format: AAA.111#2222_aa-1234): ");
function validate(){
    if (isValidInfo(course)) {
        document.write("Valid information!");
    } else {
        documwnt.write("Invalid information.")
    }
}
```

I need to be able to click the validate button a produce either a "Valid information!" message or an "Invalid information." message. 
Any helpful guidance would be appreciated.
Right now with the code as is, the validate button does nothing. Removing the [A-Z]... and [a-z] and changing the 'i' to a 'g' gets it to work if I enter aaa.111#2222_aa-1234, but anything ELSE does not produce a message sighting invalid info.

Comment: Using the `i` flag means that there's no difference between `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]`

Comment: You have `documwnt.write()`

Comment: You need `/^[A-Z]{3}\.\d{3}#\d{4}_[a-z]{2}-\d{4}$/i`, see https://regex101.com/r/Wbg6Ex/1

Comment: Check the typo in `documwnt.write("Invalid information.")` --> `documwnt`; this is the reason why it doesn't do anything: it "crashes". Regardless of this, the regex is erroneous and @WiktorStribiżew regex is the correct one to use, but without the trailing `i`. Also, it's a good practice to use `console.log` instead of `document.write`.

Comment: @DanielF If OP really does not need case insensitivity, `i` can be safely removed. In my explanations, it is made clear. I used `i` because of the last sentence in the question (I understood it that `aaa.111#2222_aa-1234` is valid)

Comment: When you say `course info` what exactly are the forms for that. I have never seen any course codes that have fixed fields, let alone 1 format for all of them. I wouldn't put it all on the user to know the forms in advance. You should relax the restrictions and match partial forms, else users _will_ get frustrated.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```js
function isValidInfo(course) {
    var infoRegExp = /^[A-Z]{3}\.\d{3}#\d{4}_[a-z]{2}-\d{4}$/i; // Remove i flag if aaa.111#2222_aa-1234 is invalid!
    var result = infoRegExp.test(course);
    return result
}
var course = prompt("Enter course information (format: AAA.111#2222_aa-1234): ");
function validate(){
    if (isValidInfo(course)) {
        return "Valid information!";
    } else {
        return "Invalid information.";
    }
}
console.log(validate(course));
```

The [regex demo is available here](https://regex101.com/r/Wbg6Ex/1). Note that `validate()` function should be called with your `course` argument, hence I added `validate(course)` in the `console.log()`.

Also, see the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=i&re=%5E%5BA-Z%5D%7B3%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B3%7D%23%5Cd%7B4%7D_%5Ba-z%5D%7B2%7D-%5Cd%7B4%7D%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z]{3}` - three letters (case insensitive modifier makes it match lowercase letters, too)
- `\.` - a dot
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `#` - a `#` char
- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `_` - an underscore
- `[a-z]{2}` - any 2 letters
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\d{4}` - four digits  (case insensitive modifier makes it match lowercase letters, too)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that works! I see. So I do not need to designate the character class with "\d" or "\D". I can just use [A-Z]{3} without it. Also no need for the ()

Comment: @KButler Yes, and note that `i` modifier makes `[A-Z]`  = `[a-z]`

Comment: To clarify further `/[a-z][A-Z]/` is the same as `/[a-z]/i`.  `\D{3}` means specifically 3 non-digit characters, so anything which isn't `0123456789` will be matched.

Comment: @PaulJ `/[a-z][A-Z]/` is not the same as `/[a-z]/i`. `/[a-zA-Z]/` is.

Comment: Derp..  Wiiktor is correct, I just woke up, totally mistyped that.